# How do I "obtain" data for all bars/clubs in US to a database. Yelp API?

Tags: java, database, json, screen-scraping, data-mining

What I am trying to do is create a database of all bars in the united states.  I need this database to be updated semi-regularly (every week or so) to include newly opened bars.

The problem with the yelp api is they will only return 20 results.  There are over 800 bars within a 5 mile radius of me.  How can I realistically achieve my goal?

Comment: yelp `search` api have a `offset` and `limit` parameter. does they work?

Comment: Yes but the maximum number of results they will return is 20 businesses.

Comment: have you contacted them in order to directly purchase the data?

Comment: @Randy, no I have not.  But what is the fun in that :)  Plus, I want to update regularly and would be nice if I could automate it.

Comment: @Eddie, yeah - if you let them know what you are doing, they might enjoy the revenue (even a small amount) and offer you a bigger than 20 at a time API call...

Comment: For what its worth, after doing some digging, yelp does not have any sort of paid access to more than the 20 business limit...

Comment: Yelp is the wrong source. Look at companies that support direct mail marketing. I've used infousa.com with great success in the past. I just ran a search that identified 56,377 bars in the USA. I found their prices reasonable when I was doing this stuff, but I wasn't targeting the whole country.

Answer (score 1):

you need to write a crawler that will spider the site to get the link structure than visit each page and scrape the listings. Alternatively you can use the API and just make as many requests as you need to get all of the results.

Comment: I wanted to do it as legit as possible.  I was thinking use the API and make as many requests as needed, but I would imagine that would give me a bunch of duplicates, and I could never really be sure that I got every single one...

Comment: @Eddie I didn't know that screen scraping is illegal. If the info is in the public domain why can't it be used? Google scrapes all day and all night and uses the info they receive to make a living.

Answer (score 0):

If you can access the data from web pages, then you can use IRobotSoft Web Scraper to extract the data and save them to database.  Check if demos here http://irobotsoft.com/help/ are similar to what you want.